# HTML/CSS website margin problems

Tags: html, css

Do I really need a margin-top 70% in order to put content on bottom? Is this right? Or am i doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more information about your problem?

Comment: what you need excactly, body css html code?

Comment: @Albance can you add your html and css so we can see what is going on, because your other divs should be pushing the other divs down.

Comment: Please post your HTML + CSS code as well along with the question. You may please use jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To position two elements side by side, one should not use float:left; and float:right. You can use display:inline-block and position all the three divs.

Answer (score 2):

In order to display any **CONTENT** (possibly wrapped in '') in bottom of web page you dont need to manage it through `margin` or `padding`.

You can achieve this code

```
#footer-div {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Please replace `footer-div` with the actual class / id of the div which you want display in the bottom.

Comment: @Albance - I just tried to give you the generalized solution in my answer - perhaps it would a good **exercise** for you to try it and get the solution particular to your problem. Most important part of my answer `position` and `bottom margin` parameters - which will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap visainfo1 and visainfo2 with a container and set clear:both.

Comment: but what to do with visainfo3 why marge 70%?